# libc-bin post install script failing with error code 135

Tags: apt, glibc

I am running ParrotOS on a bootable USB drive. I ran apt update and it failed with the output:

```
$sudo apt upgrade

APT on Parrot behaves differently than Debian.
apt upgrade is equivalent to apt full-upgrade in Debian,
and performs a complete system update.

Use apt safe-upgrade to perform a partial upgrade.





Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libopengl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  amd64-microcode bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs btrfs-progs burpsuite
  ca-certificates-java codium distro-info-data dnsutils exim4-base
  exim4-config exim4-daemon-light firefox-esr fonts-opensymbol ghostscript
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 golang-1.19 golang-1.19-doc
  golang-1.19-go golang-1.19-src gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-x intel-media-va-driver
  intel-microcode inxi iproute2 libapache2-mod-php7.4 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libavresample4 libavutil56 libblas3 libbrlapi0.8 libbsd0 libcups2 libgs9
  libgs9-common libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libigdgmm12 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libjson-c5 libkpathsea6 liblapack3 libldb2 liblua5.3-0 libmariadb3
  libncurses-dev libncurses5 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libnode72 libpostproc55
  libpq5 libprotobuf-lite23 libraw20 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-writer librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsmbclient libssh-4
  libssh-gcrypt-4 libssl1.1 libswresample3 libswscale5 libsynctex2
  libtinfo-dev libtinfo5 libtinfo6 libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3
  libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libwbclient0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libyajl2 logrotate
  mariadb-client-10.5 mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-common mariadb-server
  mariadb-server-10.5 mariadb-server-core-10.5 ncurses-term nodejs nodejs-doc
  openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless openssl openvpn parrot-menu php7.4-cli php7.4-common
  php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline postgresql-13
  postgresql-client-13 python3-brlapi python3-click python3-ldb python3-samba
  python3-typing-extensions python3-uno qemu-guest-agent ruby-activemodel
  ruby-activerecord ruby-activesupport ruby-nokogiri samba samba-ad-provision
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules smbclient uno-libs-private ure xbrlapi
146 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,041 MB of archives.
After this operation, 52.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...
Bus error
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/local/lib:
/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64/lib:
    liboramysql19.so -> liboramysql19.so
    libocijdbc19.so -> libocijdbc19.so
    libociei.so -> libociei.so
    libocci.so.19.1 -> libocci.so.19.1
    libnnz19.so -> libnnz19.so
    libmql1.so -> libmql1.so
    libipc1.so -> libipc1.so
    libclntshcore.so.19.1 -> libclntshcore.so.19.1
    libclntsh.so.19.1 -> libclntsh.so.19.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Bus error
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 135
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
Scanning application launchers
Removing duplicate launchers or broken launchers
Launchers are updated
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libopengl0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  amd64-microcode bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs btrfs-progs burpsuite
  ca-certificates-java codium distro-info-data dnsutils exim4-base
  exim4-config exim4-daemon-light firefox-esr fonts-opensymbol ghostscript
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 golang-1.19 golang-1.19-doc
  golang-1.19-go golang-1.19-src gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-x intel-media-va-driver
  intel-microcode inxi iproute2 libapache2-mod-php7.4 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libavresample4 libavutil56 libblas3 libbrlapi0.8 libbsd0 libcups2 libgs9
  libgs9-common libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libigdgmm12 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libjson-c5 libkpathsea6 liblapack3 libldb2 liblua5.3-0 libmariadb3
  libncurses-dev libncurses5 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libnode72 libpostproc55
  libpq5 libprotobuf-lite23 libraw20 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-writer librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsmbclient libssh-4
  libssh-gcrypt-4 libssl1.1 libswresample3 libswscale5 libsynctex2
  libtinfo-dev libtinfo5 libtinfo6 libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3
  libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libwbclient0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libyajl2 logrotate
  mariadb-client-10.5 mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-common mariadb-server
  mariadb-server-10.5 mariadb-server-core-10.5 ncurses-term nodejs nodejs-doc
  openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-17-jre
  openjdk-17-jre-headless openssl openvpn parrot-menu php7.4-cli php7.4-common
  php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline postgresql-13
  postgresql-client-13 python3-brlapi python3-click python3-ldb python3-samba
  python3-typing-extensions python3-uno qemu-guest-agent ruby-activemodel
  ruby-activerecord ruby-activesupport ruby-nokogiri samba samba-ad-provision
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules smbclient uno-libs-private ure xbrlapi
146 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,041 MB of archives.
After this operation, 52.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/burpsuite_2023.7.2+0parrot3_amd64.deb' (size=482861896) member 'data.tar': lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/burpsuite_2023.7.2+0parrot3_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to write (Broken pipe)
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...
Bus error
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/local/lib:
/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64/lib:
    liboramysql19.so -> liboramysql19.so
    libocijdbc19.so -> libocijdbc19.so
    libociei.so -> libociei.so
    libocci.so.19.1 -> libocci.so.19.1
    libnnz19.so -> libnnz19.so
    libmql1.so -> libmql1.so
    libipc1.so -> libipc1.so
    libclntshcore.so.19.1 -> libclntshcore.so.19.1
    libclntsh.so.19.1 -> libclntsh.so.19.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Bus error
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 135
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
Scanning application launchers
Removing duplicate launchers or broken launchers
Launchers are updated
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

All posts I can find reference other errors and have solutions that do not work for this error.
Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The solution was [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325800). It contains some unnecessary steps however it fixed the problem.